# Ant build system for apps and sdks

Tags: ant, build.xml

I am working with build.xml and try to understand how it works when there are multiple build.xml files provided by both app and sdk.

For example, app and sdk both depends on a base-sdk, say they will both call some methods in the base-sdk, I am trying to do some pre-process work for their calls to this base-sdk (add identification params).  In what order the build process will happen ? It seems like the the build.xml in sdk does not work if i compile from the app level, only app build.xml works. Could anyone help explaining about what happens during this process? Greatly appreciated that.

Comment: What apps? What sdks? Are you looking for advise in how to setup a multi-module build in ANT? Or debug and existing build?

Comment: Thank you for the reply mark!I am a new user to ant, i got confused about how the different ant build.xml in app and sdk work. For example if i compile from the app level, how the build.xml in sdk works?